# Git removes branch, VisualStudio still shows it

Tags: git, visual-studio

I ran "git fetch --all --prune" and it deleted a branch that was merged in a pull request and then deleted - as it should. Output was:

- [deleted]             (none)     -> origin/Dave-check-libraries

However, in VisualStudio 2015 in the branches, that branch is still listed. I did create, edit in, push, and create a PR in that branch on my system.

Is there something else I need to do? Or does this branch still exist?

thanks - dave

Comment: i have two questions: 1 You had a local branch created from the remote branch? 2 The branch you are seeing on VisualStudio is a local or a remote branch?

Comment: Yes, I created the local branch on my computer. I made my changes and then published(?) the branch and pushed them up. Then did a pull request which was approved.

Comment: Then I guess that what you are seeing on VisualStudio is the _local_ branch that I would "assume" that --prune will not delete because that branch is "yours". --prune will remove your local reference to the *remote branches*, but won't touch your local branches, even if they were created from branches that got pruned (at least, I think that's the save behavior).

Comment: @Edmundo - so it's a feature :). Do I then delete the branch on my system? Yes it should be safe but I figure better to ask for something like this. Thank you

Comment: If it is indeed a local branch left over after you had deleted/pruned the remote branch and if you don't want to see it anymore, then it's ok to delete it from your local repo.

Comment: @Edmundo - if you put all your comments in an answer, I'm happy to then mark that as the answer. thanks - dave